# Magento Native Captcha for contact form not working in server

Tags: captcha, contact-us

I have created a module to display the Magento native captcha in the contact form and it is working fine on my `localhost`. But when I upload it on the server it is showing the following error

`Fatal error: Call to a member function getBlockName() on a non-object in /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Captcha/Block/Captcha.php on line 43`

I have tried some methods like clearing the cache and session files.

What can I do to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Captcha requires a `form id` which is given in captcha layout file, the code is used as

```
<action method="setFormId"><formId>contact_form</formId></action>
```

you can follow this tutorial [Captcha for contact us](http://razbakov.com/blog/585-magento-native-captcha-for-contact-form/).